# Parse signup fields background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using parse for iOS to allow users to login/register. The problem is when I try to style  my signupviewController that is a subclass of PFSignUpViewController. No matter how I do I always end up with a image behind userNameTextField and passwordTextField. I can't find any documentation or way to remove this image, does anyone know a solution to my problem?

Heres a screen shot of what I'm trying to remove:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUHFT.jpg

And here is the code Im using to create that screen:

IGSignupViewController.h:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface IGSignUpViewController : PFSignUpViewController

@end
```

IGSignupViewController.m:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
...

[self.signUpView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}];
UIView *bgView = [IGBackgroundLayer purpleGradientBackgroundViewWithRect:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[self.signUpView insertSubview:bgView atIndex:0];

...
}
```

And this is how I initiate the signupViewController from my welcomeViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  // Check if user is logged in
  if (![PFUser currentUser]) {

    // Instantiate our custom log in view controller
    IGLoginViewController *logInViewController = [[IGLoginViewController alloc] init];

    [logInViewController setDelegate:self];
    [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"friends_about_me", nil]];
    [logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword
     | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten];

    // Instantiate our custom sign up view controller
    IGSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[IGSignUpViewController alloc] init];
    [signUpViewController setDelegate:self];
    [signUpViewController setFields:PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton | PFSignUpFieldsDismissButton];
    signUpViewController.emailAsUsername = YES;
    // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
    [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];

    // Present log in view controller
    [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close.  Change the index of your new background to 2 instead of 0. The object at the zero index is the old background, and index 1 is the old fields background, both of which are baked in to the class.  Easier to just put your BG in front:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
...

UIView *bgView = [IGBackgroundLayer purpleGradientBackgroundViewWithRect:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[self.signUpView insertSubview:bgView atIndex:2];

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was in the Parse SDK when I update it to version 1.4 the problem disappeared.